# Computing the frequency of 5 in an array

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop

Very basic query here from a beginner... 
I'm looking to find the frequency of a number within an array...
In the (mangled) code below I have tried to calculate the occurances of the number 5 in the array
I'm running into problem in formulating the for loop

Heres my code attempt:

//Compute the frequency of 5 in the array named numbers

public class find  //Begin class
{

```
public static void main (String []args) //Begin main
{

    double numbers[] = {6,7,12,5,4,2,4,6,9,5,7,11,1,23,32,45,5}; //Initialise and populate array

int total = 0;
int counter = 0;
for (int x : numbers)
{
    if (numbers[] == 5; counter ++)
    {System.out.println( numbers[i] + "  ");
    }
```

}

// end code 
// *****************

Comment: Have you looked anywhere else first? That's not the syntax for if statements and array access. Examples are really helpful.

Comment: Hi Alan, got an array of Java books here! Great for general but not of help for specific stuff... But as you say examples are great. Its really down to typing up examples and playing with them to learn. I'm still at an very basic level but getting better

Comment: I was thinking about online examples, then you can quickly copy and paste and have working code. Plus theres tons more examples and verity is good too unlike a book or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numbers[] = {6,7,12,5,4,2,4,6,9,5,7,11,1,23,32,45,5};

for(int x : numbers) {
   if(x == 5)
      counter++;
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

I can see that you were trying to use a **for each** loop in your implementation. 
@Code Whisperer provides a good alternative to that, but if you do want to use a **for each** loop then you have to make sure you loop type and array type match. In your case, your array is type **double** but your loop type is **int**. Within each iteration, you're selecting an individual value in the array, so you don't need to include any brackets.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] == 5) {
        counter++;
        System.out.println(counter); // shows how many 5s you have so far
    }
 }
```

Loop through array, compare every element in the array to 5. If it is 5, increment counter by 1.

Comment: Thanks again. Brilliant. Works.  How do you just print the final number? ie.3

Comment: Just move the System.out line outside of the for loop

Comment: Not working... //Compute the frequency of 5 in the array
  int total = 0;
  int counter = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
  {
      if (numbers[i] == 5)
      {
          counter++;
    }
  }
        System.out.println(counter); // shows how many 5s you have so far